# ThreeJS multicolor material

Tags: colors, three.js, mask

##### How can I have a multicolor material in ThreeJS?

I'm looking for a way to have **a single material and use one or more b/w masks to color the surface of the model with the same amount of colors**; the masks will not blend/overlap each others, so no color blending, just some areas of one color and other of another.

I'm sure it is actually possible with ThreeJS to achieve this, but I couldn't find any example on how to do this.

Having played with Blender I'm used to assign multiple materials to specific mesh faces for easiest models and using multiple shaders (or even entire materials) with textures masks, but in a web context I assume the best practice is to have a single model/mesh to which assign a single material.

Just to be clear, the final use case will be a 3d model created with external tool (blender, maya, etc) with all necessary textures to recreate a single material, this way I can asynchronously download each assets for page speed.

The problem is how then to recreate the final material with all the assets.

Comment: You CAN use more than one material per geometry, using groups (https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.groups). You can also use a single material and add a colour attribute to each vertex and make a custom material that takes them into account the way you like. Do either of these approaches sound like what you need?

Comment: the problem with this 2 approaches is that I'm bounding my color variations to vertex positions, thus to edges and faces; what i'm looking for is a way to be able to color a single face using a mask, e.g. drawing a circle in the middle of a triangle.

Comment: Just throwing it out there, but this sounds like the job for a texture and a very precise UV map. And if that's not the way, perhaps a custom shader that can take the triangle index of the fragment and color it based on that?

Comment: @TheJim01 that's not exactly how I would do it since rastered texture for diffuse color + uv maps would give me static colors, I would use a b/w mask to define the areas to color and a custom material/shader to be able to programmatically input and/or change at runtime the colors